# How to give .requestFocus() for first search of a text in the layout in Android Studio using Java?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

In my android app, I want to give `.requestFocus()` for the first search of a text which is in textView using Java in an android studio. Here is my code snippet that I had gone through...

```
String mytext = "Menu1";
mytext.requestFocus();
```

But here I got error..

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: ``Cannot resolve method 'requestFocus()'`` @EvyatarCohen

Comment: String never gets focus, You need View. Please clear your requirements first mentioning what do you wan to do?

Comment: My declaration is right? @EvyatarCohen

Comment: Hi @Md.Asaduzzaman... In my case i don't know the ID to get the View. I know only text present in the textVIew. Because my textView is dynamic one

Comment: requestFocus() method works on views brother.Do like this : edtTxt.requestFocus();   or edtTxt.setFocusable(true);   to get your desired answer.Thanks.....

Answer (score 0):

Request focus is only for the views not for the primitive data types.
For the Textview to keep in focus by using XML or programmatically,

```
// Parent view
LinearLayout ll = …
final int childCount = ll.getChildCount();
for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
  View v = ll.getChildAt(i);
  // Check is v is instanceof TextView.
}
```

Xml attributes,

```
// Based on the requirement
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode = "true"
```

Programmatically,

```
TextView text = view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
text.requestFocus();
```

Answer (score 0):

**requestFocus** is for a **View** like **EditText**, not a **string**. You can use it like this:

```
textview.requestFocus();
```

or
    `<TextView...>
        <requestFocus />
    </TextView>`

Comment: Sr for not understand your question fully. You cannot requestFocus a string. What do you want with your textview? If possible, can you post a illustration, pls?